# HDMI no output in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, display, hdmi

I bought a new laptop and installed CentOS 7.2 parallel with the original Win10 inside (dual system). When using Win10, I can see HDMI outputs to an extra monitor without problem, but it just shows no signal when I am in the CentOS.

I tried to find the solution on the Internet, but there is no luck. Many questions are about why HDMI doesn't output audio, but mine is it outputs nothing at all.

I then tried to gather some information which might be needed, and I attached the commands and the result as follows.

**xrandr --verbose**

```
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080 
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x17f) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
Identifier: 0x17e
Timestamp:  70549
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
_MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
1920x1080 (0x17f) 159.667MHz *current
    h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
    v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

**lspci -v | grep VGA -A20**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Pegatron Device 22c4
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [100] #1b
Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
Capabilities: [300] #13

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
Subsystem: Pegatron Device 22c8
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at b122a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
```

I am wondering whether the system can detect the HDMI cable plug-in/plug-out event or not, so I use `dmesg -wH` to wait for the event. I found when I plug in the Ethernet cable or USB device, it shows up some information, but there is totally no response when I plug in the HDMI cable. (but it shouldn't be a hardware problem because my Win10 can recognize it)

Then I guess it is a driver problem. I tried the command below.

**lsmod | grep hdmi**

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47849  1
snd_hda_codec         137386  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           57760  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm               105835  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd                    83425  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
```

**rpm -qa | egrep "hdmi|intel"**

```
xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-26.20160929.el7.x86_64
```

According to the information above, I think I have the needed driver (I guess) installed. However, the system cannot recognize it (dmesg no response). Can anybody help me on this issue? Any hint only is also appreciated.